# OData $format system query option causes Bad Request 400

Tags: wcf, json, odata

I have a very simple Reflection-based OData sample the runs fine and generates json when I use the Accept header as indicated.  However, I cannot get it to work with the $format=json parameter.  Whenever I add that parameter, I get Bad Request.  According to this, it seems like it should work: [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728283(v=VS.100).aspx)

Note that other system query options like $select do work okay.  This is .Net 4 running via VS2010.

Comment: This is a good question.  The MSDN documentation is misleading as it shows the `$format` param as a valid parameter, but deliberately prevents you from requesting data formatted as JSON straight out of the box.  This was supported in 3.5, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$format=json` out of the box against a .NET 4 WCF Data Service will not work even though the OData Spec says it's supported.  I'm not sure exactly why Microsoft does not support it directly.  But there are two workarounds to this situation - one feels a little hacky, and the other makes some sense.

First, the solution that feels a little hacky is to build an HttpHandler that intercepts your request, reads the `$format=json` querystring parameter and then adds an accepts header to your request (while removing the offending `$format=json` parameter).  This is described in [this blog post](http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/05/wcf-data-services-format-json/comment-page-1/).

The second solution, which sounds a little better, is to decorate your data service with a `[JSONPSupportBehavior]` attribute.  This makes a little more sense and is a little easier to implement (since you don't have to build an HttpHandler).  Here are some useful links:

- [Blog post](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/06/17/The-query-parameter-_27002400_format_2700_-begins-with-a-system_2D00_reserved-_270024002700_-character-but-is-not-recognized.aspx) describing how to use
  it.
- [Link to download](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=DataServicesJSONP&DownloadId=11208) the source code for the `[JSONPSupportBehavior]`
  attribute (yes, you'll have to build
  it -- I haven't found a compiled
  download).

I like the attribute approach, I just wish it wasn't a download off CodePlex...it just doesn't sound that supported yet.  But that's just my opinion.

Honestly, if you have control, the best approach is just to add an accepts header to your request of `application/json`, and your service will automatically return JSON formatted results.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links--I googled this to death and never found those.  I didn't realize $format was reserved which explains the 400.  Am I missing a setting that would show me those errors?

Comment: Another thing I tried was overriding OnStartProcessingRequest on my service and doing a 
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json
when I detected a custom "&format=json" parameter but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: JSONPSupportBehavior looks good--a bit more code than one might want but it looks like a useful tool to know how to use.

Comment: I see the error in Google Chrome - I didn't really test for the error message in IE or FF.  Maybe turn customErrors `mode=Off` in your web.config?  Or run it through Fiddler and you should see the error message.  Glad this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who comes across this... You can now use [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com) and inherit from ODataService rather than DataService to automatically enable this functionality.